# Powershell: Unwanted DateTime conversion when inserted into CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime

I am having unwanted conversion while trying to place a `toString(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00)` format of `DateTime` variable in CSV. If I directly place `DateTime` variable in CSV without converting it into `toString(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00)`, I have no issues but the reason I am converting is I want to eliminate seconds (i.e make `ss`=00)

```
#$file is CSV file path
$dateTi_var = (Get-Date "2020-01-01 00:00:00")
$dateTi_str_var = $dateTi_var.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")  
$dateTi_str_var # displays output as "2020-01-01 00:00:00"

#but when stored in CSV
Add-Content -Path $file -Value $dateTi_str_var #issue -> the data is placed in CSV as format "01/01/2020 12:00 AM"
Add-Content -Path $file -Value $dateTi_var  #no issues -> the data is placed in CSV as format "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Comment: not reproducible on my end. neither in v5 nor in v7

Comment: Are you perhaps importing/opening the csv with a tool like Excel or Google Sheets to verify? Spreadheet software loves to auto-format date-like strings

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Content -Path $file -Value (Get-Date $dateTi_var -Second 00)
```

solved the issue, it eliminates seconds also CSV does not create any formatting issue.